# How to change Coercion Type of email body to html from text using outlook add-in, I am using Office js to access email body from add-in

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, add-in, outlook-web-addins

I have an outlook add-in build in react using office js, I need to insert links as anchor tag which works fine when email body is in "html" format but when I reply to email which is in "text" format the Coercion type of email body is set to "text" by outlook as default. I can read this type by Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getTypeAsync. Is there a way to set it to html from add-in?

I want to add a link with one word title which I could not do if email body is in plain text.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the feature to set the bodyType, as you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: I did this just now: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/allow-setting-bodytype-to-html-in-outlook-from-add-in/idi-p/3596975. Hope it doesn't take too long to have this integrated, as it is an important function, IMHO.